# php artisan migrate error: nodename nor servname provided or not know

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker-compose, laradock

I'm in trouble with my laradock project: i have downloaded and installed docker and i have successfully completed the setup of my laravel project with laradock. I use php 7, laravel(5.5.14) and the latest version of laradock. I start my project writing in shell:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql
```

and all services starts. My env file is:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

But when i try to use the migration with

```
php artisan migrate
```

i receive this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations) 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known 
PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

My db called homestead is created and it works. In my laravel project, under the migration folder i have 3 files php: *create_user_table*, *create_password_reset_table* and *create_customer_table*( i have wrote this file). I need to create a table in my db called *customer* with some colums:

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->boolean('azienda');
        $table->string('iva');
        $table->string('ds');
        $table->boolean('fatres');
        $table->string('cf');
        $table->string('mail');
        $table->string('telefono');
        $table->integer('sponsor');
        $table->string('indinst');
        $table->string('civinst');
        $table->string('cityInst');
        $table->string('capinst');
        $table->string('provinst');
        $table->string('indf');
        $table->string('civf');
        $table->string('capf');
        $table->string('provf');
        $table->string('cityFatt');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

How can i complete the migration and create the table? Thank you for answer!

Comment: Where are you running this command? (inside docker, outside docker)

Comment: Hi! I ran the command outside the docker, but i have solved all the thing executing the bash inside the docker and repeated the command. It worked!

Answer (score 10):

@Stefano Zaniboni answered this in a comment but to expand:

I ran across this issue because I'm used to running `php artisan` commands in my local directory rather than in a virtualbox / vagrant box / docker container.

The [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#running-migrations) mention that you need to run the `php artisan migrate` command from within your virtual machine.

If you're using docker, you can get your container id using `docker ps`.  Then to ssh into the container use `docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/bash`.  Then just `cd` into your project directory and run `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: I was bit by this. In my case I was trying to run a migrate refresh and this is what worked: docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> php artisan migrate:refresh