# Laraver 8.40 running on Docker issues a MySQL 2002 error when trying to migrate via artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

This is a completely fresh installation of Laravel (because i was hoping that would fix the issue), which now makes it version `8.40.00`. And to run it, i go through `sail`, by doing: `./vendor/bin/sail up -d`.

Even though the initial `.env` file has database credentials which don't work (sail:password), the database connection works after quickly changing it to (root:"").

This makes it so that my app, when accessed through the browser, can connect to the database(!) I have successfully created a new table, and can read and display data from it on the page.

However, when running `php artisan migrate`, it outputs:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_hello and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
> 674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
> 675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
> 676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
> 677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
> ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
> 679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 680▕             );
> 681▕         }
> 682▕
>
> ```
>  +33 vendor frames
> ```

A lot of existing questions about this error (just the `2002` error in general; not mentioning artisan) seem to suggest changing the `DB_HOST` to MySQL's container name from Docker will solve it. But in my case, both the (initial) value of `"mysql"` and the name of the docker container produce the same result, and generate the same error.

So, when accessing the app through the browser, the database connection works; when running an artisan command, it outputs a `2002` error.

What is causing this? And how is it correctly dealt with?

Comment: Where are you running the migrate command - [in the container, or on the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46725734/php-artisan-migrate-error-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-know)?  After setting your DB_HOST to the name of the container, [did you try clearing the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260172/sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-nodename-no)?

Comment: Yup, it was because i was running it on the host... what do we do now, do i delete this question, or do you wanna post that as an answer so i can accept?

Comment: Glad you got it working.  And thanks, but I guess it is really a duplicate so I think it should be closed as a dup.